# How do I start an animation without canceling touches?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a `UIView` nested in a `UIView`. When I animate the frame and alpha of the inner view, touches in the outer view get canceled. Can I stop that from happening?

Comment: How are you animating? Are you using UIView's block animation methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [block based animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html) methods.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
     delay:0.0 
     options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                   | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
     animations:^{
          //your animation code
     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
          //your code when animation finished..
}];
```